# Salesforce Sandbox Omniauth for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, omniauth

i'm trying to enable login by salesforce accounts through [omniauth-salesforce Gem](https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce) for a sandbox accounts, but it always redirect to login.salesforce.com and i want to redirect to test.salesforce.com

in device.rb file i have

```
config.omniauth :salesforce, configatron.salesforce.app_id, configatron.salesforce.app_secret
```

so i tried to replace this line with

```
config.omniauth :salesforce_sandbox, configatron.salesforce.app_id, configatron.salesforce.app_secret
```

or

```
config.omniauth OmniAuth::Strategies::SalesforceSandbox, configatron.salesforce.app_id, configatron.salesforce.app_secret
```

but both failed the first failed with error

```
Not found. Authentication passthru.
```

and the second failed with error

```
undefined method `to_sym' for OmniAuth::Strategies::SalesforceSandbox:Class
```

Comment: Did u found some work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Class name SalesforceSandbox so when using salesforce_sandbox for

```
require "omniauth-salesforce"
config.omniauth :salesforce, configatron.salesforce.app_id, configatron.salesforce.app_secret
config.omniauth :salesforce_sandbox, configatron.salesforce_sandbox.app_id, configatron.salesforce_sandbox.app_secret
```

this one didn't work so i forked the gem and by changing the name to Salesforcesandbox so it now works this way:

```
require "omniauth-salesforce"
config.omniauth :salesforce, configatron.salesforce.app_id, configatron.salesforce.app_secret
config.omniauth :salesforcesandbox, configatron.salesforce_sandbox.app_id, configatron.salesforce_sandbox.app_secret
```

i forked it here:

```
gem "omniauth-salesforce", ">=1.0.3", :git => 'git://github.com/mohamed-mahmoud/omniauth-salesforce.git'
```